# For loops vs standard library algorithms with a relatively old compiler

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I know code is better when there are not any confusing `for` loops in it. And it is always good to reuse the standard library algorithms when possible. However, I find that the syntax of iterators and algorithms looks really confusing.

I want to give a real life example from my current project: I want to copy the contents of `vector<vector<QString>> in` into `vector<QVariant> out`. I can't see the difference between:

```
for (int i = 0; i < in[0].size(); i++ ) 
{ 
    if(in[0][i].isNull() || in[0][i].isEmpty() ) 
        out[i] = "NONE";
    else
        out[i] = in[0][i];
}
```

and that:

```
std::transform(in[0].begin(), in[0].end(), out.begin(), [](const QString& a)->QVariant{
    if(a.isNull() || a.isEmpty() ) 
        return "NONE";
    else
        return a;
});
```

Since we have visual studio 2012 I even have to type the return value of my lambda. After using ranges like:

```
in[0].map!( a => a.isNull() || a.isEmpty() ? "NONE" : a ).copy(out);
```

in D language I simply can't live with the `std::transform` code above. And I am not even sure whether it is better than a basic `for` loop. My question is: is code using `std::transform` above better than the `for` loop?

Comment: VS2012 already implements type deduction for return types in lambda expression. You don't have to specify it. But Jerry Coffin's answer is better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At least in my opinion, the main problem here is that `transform` is simply the wrong tool for the job.

What you're trying to do is exactly what `std::replace_copy_if` does, so (no big surprise) it does it a lot more neatly.

I don't have Qt installed on the machine at hand, so I took the liberty of replacing your `QVariant` and `QString` code to just a `std::vector<std::string>`, but I believe the same basic idea should apply with the Qt types as well.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {   
    std::vector<std::string> input { "one", "two", "", "three" };
    std::vector<std::string> output;

    // copy input to output, replacing the appropriate strings:
    std::replace_copy_if(input.begin(), input.end(),
                         std::back_inserter(output),
                         [](std::string const &s) { return s.empty(); }, 
                         "NONE");

    // and display output to show the results:
    std::copy(output.begin(), output.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

For the moment, this just replaces empty strings with `NONE`, but adding the null check should be pretty trivial (with a type for which `isNull` is meaningful, of course).

With the data above, I get the result you'd probably expect:

```
one
two
NONE
three
```

I should probably add, however, that even this is clearly pretty verbose. It will be nice when we at least have ranges added to the standard library, so (for example) the `input.begin(), input.end()` can be replaced with just `input`. The result still probably won't be as terse as the D code you gave, but at least it reduces the verbosity somewhat (and the same applies to most other algorithms as well).

If you care about that, there are a couple of `range` libraries you might want to look at--[Boost Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html) for one, and (much more interesting, in my opinion) [Eric Neibler's range library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/tree/master/include/range/v3).

Comment: Thanks a lot especially for the links .

Answer (score 3):

Your code can be improved by using `?` `:` (it might be sensible to create a `static QVariant QVNone;` that you could use).

```
std::transform(in[0].begin(), in[0].end(), out.begin(),
               [](const QString& a)   // for C++14: (auto& a)
                  { return a.isNull() || a.isEmpty() ? QVariant("NONE") : a; }
              );
```

Note: [this page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qvariant.html) documents `QVariant(const QString&)`, so the compiler should be able to work out a common type for the `?` `:` values.

C++11 provides automatic determination of lambda return type when there's a single return statement - see syntax (3) [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).  C++14 already introduces the ability to accept the argument ala `(auto& a)`.  Ranges over container elements would help simplify such loops further; I think they're proposed for C++17; a relevant paper's available [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4128.html).

There are also functional (non-Standard) libraries for C++ that may offer you a notation more like the one you document for D.  Library recommendations are off-topic here, but Google should turn up some candidates without much effort.

Comment: I am working on very old code base that indexes starts with 1.  To simplify I wrote int i = 0 and changed in[0][i-1] to in[0][i] before posting. I forgot about <=size() which I also edited now.  I am very happy about "ranges over container elements" improvement.Looking forward to it .

Comment: @KadirErdemDemir: I mainly mentioned the indexing error to show how easily such mistakes can be made, whether during the original write or during "maintenance" changes: one benefit of declarative operations (such as the Standard algorithms), is that there's a *little* less room for that class of errors.  I hadn't taken a huge interest in the range proposal, but you've got me reading and I'm looking forward to it more now myself.  Cheers.